# Pane children overlapping the Pane border

Tags: javafx, geometry, border, pane

I am trying to generate random circles on click in a Pane, but some of them are appearing outside the Pane border as seen in the pic [Pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mda7s.png)... this is the code that generates the circle

```
 private void createCircle(){
            double  r, g, b, o, radius;
            Random generator = new Random();
            radius =50;
            float x = (float)(Math.random()*(700+1));
            float y = (float)(Math.random()*(700+1));
            cc.setLayoutX(x);
            cc.setLayoutY(y);
            cc.setRadius(radius);
            r = generator.nextDouble();
            g = generator.nextDouble();
            b = generator.nextDouble();
            o = generator.nextDouble();
            cc.setFill(new Color(r,g,b,o));
            pane.getChildren().addAll(cc);
            cc.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
                pane.getChildren().remove(cc);
                createCircle();
            });
        }
```

The pane predWidth is 700 and prefHeight is also 700... I am guessing the cc.setLayoutX() and cc.setLayoutY() are wrong but I couldn't find any other way around it

Comment: [mcve] please .. that said: make sure you understand the behavior of layouts (read at least the package/class doc, better work through an appropriate tutorial)

Comment: I was reading through documentation and I see that a Pane does not clip the content at it's bounds by default. So I will have to manually clip the circles... I will update the question as soon as I come up with a solution

Comment: You have to take the circle radius into account.

Comment: @Sedrick exactly what I did !.I didn't solve the clipping problem but I changed x and y coordinates of the circle  between a minimum and a maximum value + the radius and the circles are now being displayed only inside the pane

Comment: Are you still having an issue?

Comment: as mentioned, I skipped the clipping and adjusted the positioning of the circles inside the pane... now idk if I should close the question or search further into the clipping problem